# dup error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c, pipe, pipeline, system-calls

Documentation of dup says that return value in new file descriptor or on error -1.

I'm getting this error, and I really don't know why:

```
mav@mav-MS-7592:~/FRI/OSIZPIZ$ gcc pipe.c  -o pipe
pipe.c: In function ‘main’:
pipe.c:26:16: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
   STDIN_FILENO = dup(fd[0]);
```

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    //fd[0] - reading
    //fd[1] - writing
    int fd[2];
    pid_t childpid;

    if(pipe(fd) == -1) errexit("pipe");

    //child 0
    //parent PID
    if((childpid = fork()) == -1) errexit("fork");

    if(childpid == 0){
        close(fd[1]);
        STDIN_FILENO = dup(fd[0]);
    }else{
        close(fd[0]);
        STDOUT_FILENO = dup(fd[1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I know, I could avoid this with dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO); but I wanna use just dup...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `STDIN_FILENO` (and `STDOUT_FILENO`) may be *macros*, you don't really know what they do or what they expand to. You should look at the preprocessor output to see what's it really is.

Comment: Oh, thanks... Totally forgot about that... `STDIN_FILENO` is constant set to 0 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

`STDIN_FILENO` is a [constant defined in `unistd.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/unistd.h.html):

> The following symbolic constants are defined for file streams:
>
> `STDIN_FILENO`
>       File number of *stdin*. It is 0.
>   `STDOUT_FILENO`
>       File number of *stdout*. It is 1.
>   `STDERR_FILENO`
>       File number of *stderr*. It is 2.

As it is a constant, you *can't* reassign them.